# C# WP8.1 - Displaying a MapIcon on top of a Route when using Bing Maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I am just playing around with bing maps at the moment. I have followed the tutorials to create routes and add mapicons etc, however I have found that a mapIcon wont show if it on the route. I have tried playing with the Z-Index property of the mapIcon, however this seemed to have little effect, as I think it only has an effect with other MapElements.

Does anyone else know a way to make this happen?

My current code for creating the route and trying to set a MapIcon on the destination is (For abit of Content MapFunctions is just a static class I've made for functons such as finding the route, get the current location etc):

```
    private async void DrawRoute()
    {
        // Check if a destination has been set
        if(MapFunctions.destination != null)
        {
            route = await MapFunctions.GetRouteAsync(MapFunctions.destination.Point);

            if (route != null)
            {
                // Use the route to initialize a MapRouteView.
                MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(route.Route);
                viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Yellow;
                viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Black;


                // Add the new MapRouteView to the Routes collection
                // of the MapControl.
                MyMap.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);

                // Fit the MapControl to the route.
                await MyMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(
                    route.Route.BoundingBox,
                    null,
                    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.None);

                AddDestinationMapElement(MapFunctions.destination.Point);

                // Start timer to update the remaining time of the journey
                UpdateRemainingTime_Tick(this, new Object());
                dispatcherTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog("An error occured while trying to calculate your route. Please try again later.", "Error");
                await message.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddDestinationMapElement(Geopoint dest)
    {
        MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
        MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = dest.Position.Latitude,
            Longitude = dest.Position.Longitude
        });

        MapIcon1.Visible = true;
        MapIcon1.ZIndex = int.MaxValue;
        MapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/mapIcon.png"));
        MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
        MapIcon1.Title = "Destination";
        MyMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add pushpin on top of your elements, you can use MapOverlay that will allow you to add pushpin (with image or any XAML element) into your map control:

```
MapOverlay pushpinStart = new MapOverlay();
pushpinStart.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
pushpinStart.Content = new Image()
                           {
                               Source =
                                   new BitmapImage(
                                   new Uri("../Assets/Ui/ui-pin-start.png", UriKind.Relative))
                           };
pushpinStart.GeoCoordinate = posCollection[0];
```

If you want to stay with MapIcon, then the rendering engine will calculate what's best to be displayed based on the zoom level and current location as well as other elements collision algorithm's result. So I'm not sure that what you're looking for.

And for WP8.1, here is the equivalent code:

```
Image iconStart = new Image();
iconStart.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Ui/ui-pin-start.png"));
this.Map.Children.Add(iconStart);
MapControl.SetLocation(iconStart, new Geopoint(pos[0]));
MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(iconStart, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had never seen the MapOverlay class before, definitely sounds like they maybe a better choice than MapIcons for this situation.

Comment: Seems like the MapOverlay class is only available in WP8, not WP8.1, as I can't find it in any namespace for WP8.1

Comment: I've added WP8.1 equivalent code to help you out, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: To point out another difference, MapIcons are rendered by the map control itself, while a MapOverlay is really an overlay in XAML. So overlays may be slower when there are lots of them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get no error but I can't see a pushpin on the map